# How does Aurora work in regions with only two zones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

The Aurora documentation states that data is replicated six ways, across three availability zones. The Canada region (`ca-central-1`) offers Aurora as an option, yet only has two availability zones. How is data replication handled in regions with only two availability zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to answer a similar question in a training I'm giving.

The region in question no longer has only 2 AZs, but 3 official ones, which are called:

- `ca-central-1a`
- `ca-central-1b`
- `ca-central-1d`

Curiously the `ca-central-1c` is left out, which leads me to believe there has been a sort of unofficial or stripped down AZ in place previously.

Looking at the [official launch news for the third AZ](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-open-third-availability-zone-in-the-aws-canada-central-region/) they explicitly state, that for example S3 previously replicated its data across three AZs, even if only two were available.

> It’s important to notice that Amazon S3 storage classes that replicate data across a minimum of three AZs, are always doing so, even when fewer than three AZs are publicly available.

So there was probably an unofficial/non-public third AZ present previously.

Answer (score 0):

Initially AWS was having only 2 AZ for canada region.In june 2020, they added one more AZ to that.